# Работа с классами jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Учу JS. В чем суть. Есть инпут поиска (.search-input). изначально скрыт. Есть кнопка (.search), при клике на которую он появляется. Нужно сделать так чтобы пр клике по кнопке он появлялся, а при клике на странице - исчезал. То есть addClass и removeClass. Пробовал реализовать таким образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.search').click(function(){
                    $('.search-input').addClass('show');
                    $(!'.search').click(function(){
                        $('.search-input').removeClass('show');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

но запутался. подскажите правильное решение, если можно с ссылкой на источник.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.search-input').on('blur', function (e) {$(this).removeClass('show');});
  $('.search').click(function() {
    $('.search-input').addClass('show').focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.search-input {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class="search-input" /><br />
<input type='button' value="Show search field" class="search" />
```

Comment: с фокусом - хорошая мысль

Comment: @Igor, Сам восхищаюсь собой :)

Comment: а ссылкой на теорию\примеры, не поделитесь? а то многое, к примеру ху из 'blur' - непонятно..

Comment: @Антон, Какие ссылки нужны? На обработчик кнопки вешаем слушатель клика, внутри назначаем класс видимости и сразу фокус на элемент поля. А на самом поле слушаем событие `blur`, которое срабатывает при потере форуса с поля. Т. е. при клике в любое другое место. Тогда просто убираем класс, показывающий поле.

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативное решение (в Сафари не работает):

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  $("input").addClass('force-show').focus().removeClass('force-show')
})
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

input.force-show, input:focus {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show input</button> <input>
```